# How to find the percentage of a single product of a supplier's total revenue?

Tags: sql, percentage, price, supplier, revenue

There are multiple suppliers and each has sold multiple products. How would I find the percentage of the revenue of one of their products against that supplier's total sales in SQL?

Here is an example of data I have to work with:

| supplier | product | price of product | quantity sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Supplier A | Apples | $2 | 1 |
| Supplier A | Shoes | $3 | 2 |
| Supplier B | Shirts | $1 | 3 |

The revenue of Supplier A's apples should be $2, their total revenue is $8. So the percentage of Supplier A's apples against total sales should be 25%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use divide values . . . and use window functions:

```
select supplier, product, sum(price * quantity),
       sum(price * quantity) / sum(sum(price * quantity)) over (partition by supplier) as ratio
from t
group by supplier, product;
```